# In IE8, jQuery can't parser Width attribute in XML

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer

I have a problem when I upgrade jQuery v1.10.1.

I have a xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profile Version="1.23">
    <Object Width="100" Height="100" />
</Profile>
```

And I write a little JavaScript snippet to load data from XML.

```
(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'sample.xml',
        success: function (data) {
            if (typeof data === 'string') {
                xml = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                xml.async = false;
                xml.loadXML(data);
            } else {
                xml = data;
            }

            $(xml).find('Object').each(function () {
                var w = $(this).attr('Width');
            })
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

The above code works fine when I use jQuery 1.9.1. But it shows error when I use jQuery v1.10.0 or v1.10.1, it can't parser 'Width' attribute.

By the way, I load jQuery library by its official CDN (http://code.jquery.com/) directly.

Anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: typo here? $(this).attr('aidth'

Comment: Oh, thank you. I modified it in my post.

Comment: What if you are using: var w = $(this).prop('Width');  Same result? BTW, check if in IE8 attribute is not parsed as 'width' not 'Width'

Comment: When I use .prop(), the value shows 'undefined'. I had tried lower-case before, it still not works...